# How to add new recipe with react?

Tags: reactjs

[error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFPZ4.png)     [Full github code](https://github.com/JanLinhart/ackee)
Okay so I am trying to add new recipe to recipes but it wont work, I am not really sure how it works with axios.post either. Not sure if my way is really the way but when I submit the form, it throws POST error. I really appreaciate any advice. Thanks

Recipe.js

```
    import React from 'react'
    import './Form.css'
    import {RecipeContext} from './RecipeContext';
    import {useContext,useState} from 'react';
    import axios from 'axios';
    
    function Form() {
        const [nazev,setNazev]=useState('');
        const[uvodni,setUvodni]=useState('');
        const[ingredience,setIngredience]=useState('');
        const[postup,setPostup]=useState('');
        const[time,setTime]=useState(0);
        const [score,setScore]=useState(0);
        const{recipes,setRecipes}=useContext(RecipeContext)
        const onSubmit=e=>{
          const newRecipe={id:Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000000),
          description:postup,name:nazev,duration:time,info:uvodni,score:+score}
          
          e.preventDefault()
          setRecipes([...recipes,newRecipe])
          axios.post("https://cookbook.ack.ee/api/v1/recipes")
             
        
        }
        
        return (
            <>
            <button className="pridat" onClick={onSubmit}>+</button>
            <form className="form" >
              <p className="nazev">Název receptu</p>
              <input type="text" value={nazev}
              onChange={(e) => setNazev(e.target.value)}/>
              <input type="text" className="uvodni" placeholder="Úvodní text"
              value={uvodni}
              onChange={(e) => setUvodni(e.target.value)}/>
              <h2>Ingredience</h2>
              <input placeholder="Vaše ingredience" type="text"
              value={ingredience}
              onChange={(e) => setIngredience(e.target.value)}/>
              <button>+ Přidat</button>
              <input type="text" className="postup" placeholder="Postup"
              value={postup}
              onChange={(e) => setPostup(e.target.value)}/>
             <input type="text" placeholder="Čas" className="cas" value={time}
              onChange={(e) => setTime(e.target.value)}/>
            </form>
            </>
        )
              }

export default Form
```

RecipeContext.js

```
import React,{useState,useEffect,createContext,useReducer} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import AppReducer from './AppReducer'


export const RecipeContext=createContext([[],() => {}]);

export default function RecipeProvider(props) {
    const[recipes,setRecipes]=useState([])
    const[state,dispatch]=useReducer(AppReducer,recipes)
    function addRecipe(id){
      dispatch({
        type:'ADD_RECIPE',
        payload:id
      })
    }
  
    useEffect(() => {
  axios.get('https://cookbook.ack.ee/api/v1/recipes?limit=10&offset=0')
  .then(res=>setRecipes(res.data))
  console.log(recipes)
    })   

    
  

    
    return (
       
<RecipeContext.Provider value={{recipes,setRecipes,addTransaction}}>
    {props.children}
</RecipeContext.Provider>
      
    )
}
```

AppReducer.js

```
export default (state,action)=>{
    switch(action.type){
  
        case 'ADD_RECIPE':
            return{
                ...state,
                recipes:[action.payload,...state.recipes]
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the new recipe that you want to add in the axios.post body (on the second parameter)
https://cookbook3.docs.apiary.io/#introduction/recipes

So when you call axios post to create recipe, it should be like this:

```
axios.post("https://cookbook.ack.ee/api/v1/recipes", newRecipe)
```

Comment: @jendazedniik can I see the error message of the POST request?  Maybe try using Ackee in the name of the new recipee.. because apparently it is required to include the word "ackee" in the name of the recipee

Comment: yea, just added it as a picture up there

Comment: It shows that it got error 422 which is validation error, possibly because the name of the recipe is already exist.. try submitting again with different recipe name. if it still not work, you can see the error message by opening network tab in chrome console and then submitting the recipe

Comment: I dont know why but it just doesnt add the recipe for me, does it work for you?